# How to get rspec to not show db queries and just dots with rails_12factor?

Tags: ruby, rspec

```
ruby: 2.0
rails: 3.2.17
rspec: 2.14.8
Database: mysql
```

`rspec spec` used to just output the dots.

I was getting a deprecation warning when I pushed to Heroku and recently added the `rails_12factor` gem to get around it.  Now however I get this verbose db output for each transaction  when running specs locally.
That is a great option *when I need it* otherwise it is a lot of unneeded and distracting output.

So I would like an option that will use it for Heroku but not locally.

Note this is **not** addressed by using the formatter, e.g.

```
rspec spec -fd
```

Also, if there is an error, with this level of verbosity, the error nearly always scrolls off the current page...

```
09:50:39 durrantm Castle2012 /home/durrantm/Dropnot/_/rails_apps/linker 74093480_wire_up_verify_code
$ rspec spec/models/link_spec.rb -fd
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
...
Link
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO `groups` (`created_at`, `group_description`, `group_name`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-07-12 13:50:49', 'Various jQuery examples of common situa
tions amnd solutions', 'jQuery Examples', '2014-07-12 13:50:49')
   (0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Link Load (0.6ms)  SELECT `links`.* FROM `links` WHERE (links.position IS NOT NULL) AND (1 = 1) ORDER BY links.position DESC LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `links` (`alt_text`, `content_date`, `created_at`, `group_id`, `position`, `updated_at`, `url_address`, `verified_date`, `version_number`) VALUE
S ('examples of common situations amnd solutions', NULL, '2014-07-12 13:50:49', 141, 1, '2014-07-12 13:50:49', 'http://test.com', NULL, NULL)
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (68.4ms)  ROLLBACK
  should be valid
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (0.3ms)  INSERT INTO `groups` (`created_at`, `group_description`, `group_name`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-07-12 13:50:49', 'Various jQuery examples of common situa
tions amnd solutions', 'jQuery Examples', '2014-07-12 13:50:49')
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Link Load (0.7ms)  SELECT `links`.* FROM `links` WHERE (links.position IS NOT NULL) AND (1 = 1) ORDER BY links.position DESC LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.5ms)  INSERT INTO `links` (`alt_text`, `content_date`, `created_at`, `group_id`, `position`, `updated_at`, `url_address`, `verified_date`, `version_number`) VALUE
S ('examples of common situations amnd solutions', NULL, '2014-07-12 13:50:49', 142, 1, '2014-07-12 13:50:49', 'http://test.com', NULL, NULL)
   (0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (67.6ms)  ROLLBACK
  should have attribute :group_id
   (0.3ms)  BEGIN
   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `groups` (`created_at`, `group_description`, `group_name`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2014-07-12 13:50:49', 'Various jQuery examples of common situa
tions amnd solutions', 'jQuery Examples', '2014-07-12 13:50:49')
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (0.2ms)  SAVEPOINT active_record_1
  Link Load (0.5ms)  SELECT `links`.* FROM `links` WHERE (links.position IS NOT NULL) AND (1 = 1) ORDER BY links.position DESC LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO `links` (`alt_text`, `content_date`, `created_at`, `group_id`, `position`, `updated_at`, `url_address`, `verified_date`, `version_number`) VALUE
S ('examples of common situations amnd solutions', NULL, '2014-07-12 13:50:49', 143, 1, '2014-07-12 13:50:49', 'http://test.com', NULL, NULL)
   (0.1ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
   (68.7ms)  ROLLBACK
  should have attribute :url_address
...
```

Comment: you aren't using the `rails_12factor` gem by chance are you?

Comment: Yup, that's it.   Hmmm.  I believe I added that Gem to get around deprecation warnings in pushing to Heroku.  So now I am not sure what to do.  Let me update the question to posit that I need a solution to address both.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We saw this too, it's generated by the `rails_12factor` gem and it can be surpressed, typically by just making sure that gem is only in the production group, like so:

```
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

One of the dependencies of `rails_12factor` is another gem called `rails_stdout_logging` which is causing the output you're seeing.

Comment: You could also change the log level in testing to `:warn`. https://github.com/heroku/rails_stdout_logging#set-log-level