# Rails 4.2.1 Rspec 3.3 Running Rspec prints all my sql queries to the console. How do I turn this off?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I definitely broke something somewhere. The tests run to completion and all pass, but it prints a lot of output to the console and makes it harder to debug tests. I didn't actively try to get this behavior, it just started up randomly. It's been doing this for a while so I regrettably can't just go back a few commits. My other rails projects don't do this. Does anyone have any idea what I could do to stop this?

Comment: Do you happen to have the rails_12factor gem installed? If so see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24713594/how-to-get-rspec-to-not-show-db-queries-and-just-dots-with-rails-12factor

Comment: Another potential cause is that you are redirecting the rails logger output to to STDOUT check for anything like  `ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)` in your environments and initializers.

Comment: rails_12factor seems to be the problem. I moved it to the production group and I'm not getting that sql output anymore. Thanks so much for that. I also use geocoder and I get output from that during my tests. Any idea how to get rid of that?

Answer (score 0):

As 'baron816' said, move `rails_12factor` to production group in you Gemfile.

`group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end`